# String split Java not working

Tags: java, string, split

I have tried split with some other texts, its working fine there but not here. Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?

```
private static String fileName = "jjjj.txt";

private static String userName = "xxxx";
private static String password = "yyyy";
public static void main(String args[]){

    String info = "UserName" +"|"+ userName + "|" + password + "|" + fileName;
    String tempStr[] = info.split("|");
    System.out.println(tempStr[0]);
    System.out.println(tempStr[1]);
    System.out.println(tempStr[2]);
    System.out.println(tempStr[3]);
}
```

I am getting output as :

```
U
s
e
```

What should I do to get the output as:

```
UserName
xxxx
yyyy
jjjj.txt
```

Comment: Pipe, `|`, is a **regex reserved character**. Use `\\|`.

Comment: Why would you even build a string and then split it? You can simply use `tempStr[] = {"UserName", userName, password, fileName};`. Or at least use different delimiter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the `|` in your regular expression. This should work:

```
String tempStr[] = info.split("\\|");
```